GKE Ingress Controller - Traffic Routing to Pods
I am trying to configure healthcheck with GKE Ingress Controller + Application Loadbalancer, but having issues as my health/status ports is not exposed as a Kubernetes's Service (due to the sensitive nature)
Do GKE ingress Controller supporting healthcheck via Pod's IP?
Something similar in AWS ALB Ingress Controller , where i can specify how traffic can be route to the pod
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#target-type
